# Reload and display message

Tags: javascript, reload

I want to reload page after deleting a row from table, and then display message. Below is the JavaScript code:

```
if(action == 'delete'){
  window.location.reload(true);
  //tried to set timeout here, no luck :(
  document.getElementById('messageSpan').innerHTML = "The value has been deleted."; 
}
```

It seems that the reload function is executed after the `messageSpan` content has been changed, so the reload function wipes out the `messageSpan` content.

Comment: I don't get it - you mean you want messageSpan to still be gone after the page has been reloaded?

Comment: I want to dispaly messageSpan after page reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to show the message for a defined period of time and *then* reload the page, you can use the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) function:

```
if(action == 'delete'){
  document.getElementById('messageSpan').innerHTML = "The value has been deleted."; 

  setTimeout(function () { // wait 3 seconds and reload
    window.location.reload(true);
  }, 3000);
}
```

Note that your message will be visible *only for those three seconds*, it will disappear when the page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

don't use reload. use the query string to pass a value back to your page to tell it whether the delete operation was successful or not

i.e. self.location.href = "yourPage.html?result=success"

your page should then check for the result query string item and display the appropriate message.

but have a look at jquery and ajax, you might not have to do the postback at all to refresh your grid

Answer (score 1):

Displaying a message after a page has been refreshed can be accomplished with the following:

**HTML** (insert anywhere in the BODY tag):

```
<div id="dvLoading"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#dvLoading {
    background:url(../theImages/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
```

**JQuery**:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Loader image:

[image: Loadere]

Worked like a charm for me. Hope it helps with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the page will destroy the state of the page and thus the user will never see the message HTML because it gets reset by the page reload.